# How to sum two lists together?

Tags: list, sum, erlang

I'm trying to do a sum of two list, for example:

```erlang
1> example:sum([4,5], [6,7])
[10,12]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Built-In Function `zipwith/3` in `lists` module can solve your problem

```
> lists:zipwith(fun(X, Y) -> X+Y end, [4, 5], [6, 7]).
 [10, 12]
```

Comment: Thanks, it was really helpful for me to understand

Answer (score 1):

I like the answer @doan-bui provided. It could also be solved using `zip/2` and a list comprehension.

```
> [X+Y || {X,Y} <- lists:zip([4, 5], [6, 7]).
[10, 12]
```

Comment: Thanks, it was really helpful for me.